# Experimenting with nested tuples.: Why is this saying it's got too many variables?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm reading about nested tuples at the moment and trying a very simple one. Can someone point out to where I'm going wrong?

```
albums = ("Backstreet Boys", "1991", 
          [("No place"), ("Backstreet's Back"), ("Everybody")])

for artist,year,songs in albums:
    print("Artist: {}\nYear:{}\nSongs: {}".format((artist,year,songs)))
```

Thanks for the help, everyone. :)

Comment: You are trying to unpack a single item from the `tuple`. Drop the loop `print("Artist: {}\nYear:{}\nSongs: {}".format(*albums))`

Comment: What is expected output that you try to achieve? There are couple of things to mention. When you iterate over `albums`, in first iteration you get the str `"Backstreet Boys"` and you try to unpack that str with length 15 into 3 variables - thus the error. Also the songs, e.g. `("No place")` - this is not a tuple, if you think so. Here the braces are redundant.

Comment: Try e.g. `artist,year,songs = albums`, then print each of them to see what you get

Comment: Thanks for this. If I drop the loop, I get an error when I try to add a second album saying this:
 
  Message=Replacement index 2 out of range for positional args tuple
  Source=C:\Users\jmacdonald\source\repos\Tuples1\Tuples1\Tuples1.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\jmacdonald\source\repos\Tuples1\Tuples1\Tuples1.py", line 8, in <module> (Current frame)
    print("Artist: {}\nYear:{}\nSongs: {}".format(*albums))

Comment: Please, don't post  error is comments. Edit your question. Also we don't know what you do when _try to add a second album_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the albums tuple in a list and remove the brackets in the format command.

```
albums = [("Backstreet Boys", "1991", 
          [("No place"), ("Backstreet's Back"), ("Everybody")])]

for artist,year,songs in albums:
    print("Artist: {}\nYear:{}\nSongs: {}".format(artist,year,songs))
```

That is because xou try to iterate through the tuple albums, not a list of tuples.